# Getting error lexical error: invalid char in json text

Tags: r, json, geojson, jsonlite

I am getting the error lexical error while running the following codes

```
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  highchartOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  
  output$map <- renderHighchart({
    hcmap(
      "https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-lowres.js")  # Replace "custom/world" with your map name
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I need some help on resolving it.

Comment: Please consider going back to your [past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14942617/akshay-bholee?tab=questions) and accepting an answer where provided.

Comment: Since you are using a highcharts.com-provided `.js` file, then it would seem that there is a bug in `highcharter`.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect `mapdata` before `fromJSON` (such as with `str(mapdata)`), you can see that it starts with something non-json:

```r
### from the previous version of your question
mapdata <- readLines("https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-lowres.js", warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
mapdata[1] <- gsub(".* = ", "", mapdata[1])
mapdata <- paste(mapdata, collapse = "\n")
mapdata <- stringr::str_remove(mapdata, ";$")

### divergence/exploration
str(mapdata)
#  chr "Highcharts.maps[\"custom/world-lowres\"]={\"title\":\"World, Miller projection, low resolution\",\"version\":\""| __truncated__
```

We need to remove everything up to and including that first `=` (at character 39).

```r
obj <- jsonlite::fromJSON(sub("^[^=]*=", "", mapdata))
str(obj, max.level = 1)
# List of 9
#  $ title         : chr "World, Miller projection, low resolution"
#  $ version       : chr "2.1.0"
#  $ type          : chr "FeatureCollection"
#  $ copyright     : chr "Copyright (c) 2023 Highsoft AS, Based on data from Natural Earth"
#  $ copyrightShort: chr "Natural Earth"
#  $ copyrightUrl  : chr "http://www.naturalearthdata.com"
#  $ crs           :List of 2
#  $ hc-transform  :List of 1
#  $ features      :'data.frame':   213 obs. of  4 variables:
```

---

More comments on your original (since-changed) question code:

See that your `gsub` is not doing anything:

```r
mapdata <- readLines("https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-lowres.js", warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
str(mapdata)
#  chr "Highcharts.maps[\"custom/world-lowres\"]={\"title\":\"World, Miller projection, low resolution\",\"version\":\""| __truncated__
nchar(mapdata)
# [1] 170260
mapdata[1] <- gsub(".* = ", "", mapdata[1])
nchar(mapdata)
# [1] 170260
```

So your initial `gsub` is doing nothing because of the spaces you have around `=` that are not in the data. You could remove the spaces and see if that works.

Bottom line, though, is that whatever you are doing *here* needs to be done also before you call `hcmap`.

Comment: Thank you. This does work but see my shiny app as I have updated the post. Using the same with hcmap in highcharter I am getting this error.

Comment: I don't understand. I think you just said effectively (and I'm taking some liberty here): *"now that we know we need to fix the broken json for `fromJSON`, why do we need to fix the broken json for a different function?"*

Comment: BTW, switching from mostly-base-R to shiny/highcharts is a large change to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it but it does not work in hcmap as in hcmap it tries to reconstruct the url to download the json and redo the transformation. The hcmap needs only a raw json url to download or json file. We can't do replace or anything before this else we get the error: cannot open URL 'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/Highcharts.maps["custom/world-lowres"]....